# How is the implementation of initializer_list changes the way the compiler reads?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I've just learned that we can use the standard library type `initializer_list<T>` to achieve initializing a class instance with a `{}`-delimited list of elements of type `T`. E.g.

```cpp
class X
{
public:
    X(initializer_list<int> lst)
    {
        cout << "initializer-list constructor\n";
    }
    X(int i, int j, int k)
    {
        cout << "constructor taking 3 ints\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    X a{ 1,2,3 };  // initializer-list constructor
}
```

To my knowledge, when the compiler sees `{ 1,2,3 }` in the above code, it will first seek for a constructor that takes a `initializer_list<int>`, and since there is one, it will construct a `initializer_list<int>` object out of `{ 1,2,3 }`. Had there been no constructor which takes a `initializer_list<int>`, the compiler will generate code the same as for `X a(1,2,3)`.

If the process I described above is correct, to me there is some "magic" going on here: I don't understand why defining a type (`initializer_list`) and let a function (the initializer-list constructor) accept an object of that type (say, `lst` as above) can "change" the way the function is called. By that I mean: the compiler can now understand `{}` notation so that we need not to have things like `X a({1,2,3})`, and in such cases prefers the initializer-list constructor to other constructors while treating `{}` notation as `()` notation when the initializer-list constructor is absent.

More to the point, can I define a type (say, my own `initializer_list`) such that when the compiler sees a special form of instantiation of a class (say, a `{}` initializer list), it will search for a constructor in that class that takes an object of my own `initializer_list` type, and will treat that special form of instantiation in some other way if such constructor does not exist?

In other words:

```cpp
class X
{
public:
    X(initializer_list<int> lst)
    {
        cout << "std\n";
    }
    X(my_initializer_list<int> lst)
    {
        cout << "user-defined\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    X b{ 1,2,3 };
}
```

Can I implement a `my_initializer_list` in the global scope so that the `X b{ 1,2,3 };` calls `X::X(my_initializer_list<int> lst)`?

---

My current guess is, it is a feature of the language itself that, when the compiler sees a `{}` initializer list, the compiler will always first seek for the constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list`, rather than a `initializer_list` defined in any other namespace (by that I mean, such behavior of the compiler is not implemented in the `std::initializer_list`, but is a feature designed into the compiler in the first place). May I ask if my guess is on the right track?

Comment: Your guess at the end is correct. `std::initializer_list` has special meaning in the core language. No other class (template) has this behavior. It cannot be implemented by user code.

Answer (score 1):

How the braces `{}` are interpreted when creating an instance of a class is a language feature. That is, we cannot change it so that the next time they are encountered, our custom `my_initializer_list` contstructor should be selected. What we can control is what happens once it is selected(assuming that it does gets selected by the language rules).

> Can I implement a `my_initializer_list` in the global scope so that the `X b{ 1,2,3 };` calls `X::X(my_initializer_list<int> lst)`?

So as far as i know, i don't think what you proposed is possible/doable as it requires the `{}` to be interpreted differently.

Imagine if you provided more than one `my_initializer_list` say like `my_initializer_list1`, `my_initializer_list2`, `my_initializer_list3` and suppose your class has a constructor corrresponding to each of them, then when you use `{}` for creating an instance of the class, how can it be decided which of those constructor to select.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic. This is a type of list of initialization, the rules for which are available here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization.

> Can I implement a my_initializer_list in the global scope so that the X b{ 1,2,3 }; calls X::X(my_initializer_list lst)?

No, this won't do it. Read the above rules - there's a special handling for initializer-list. If there isn't a constructor taking in an intializer-list, the constructor which matches the argument list is picked.

To call `X::X(my_initializer_list<int> lst)` you'll have to do `X b{my_initializer_list{1,2,3 }};`

Comment: Isn't "there is no magic" and "there is special handling for..." quite contradictory?

Comment: Can't this be simplified with implicit conversion?

Comment: @Sebastian well yes, you can do `X b{{1,2,3}};` but its regarded as a bad practice since its confusing in case we have overloads